# cor.gather all matrices in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

I have the list `data` which contains 31 unnamed pairwise matrices. For each matrix, I would like to use `cor.gather()` to transform them into a three-column df. For a single matrix it'd look like:

```
matrix.to.df <- matrix %>%
  cor_gather(drop.na=TRUE)
```

But in the list is tricky, as I don't have much experience with functions. I know I want something like this:

```
lapply(names(list), function(x) NewVar(list[[x]], "y", x))
```

But I don't know how to merge the two. Thank you

Comment: use `lapply(your_list, cor_gather, drop.na = TRUE)`

Comment: Great example of work smarter not harder, haha. final line of code that worked: `df <- lapply(datalist, cor_gather(datalist,drop.na = TRUE))`

Comment: That line of code cannot work since `lapply` expects a function yet `cor_gather(datalist,drop.na = TRUE)` is NOT a function. Use the code as I wrote in the first comment above. or `lapply(your_list, \(x) cor_gather(x, drop.na = TRUE))`

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  That's what I get for posting before I actually try.  My line of code returned the error `Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names can't be empty.` but your line worked just fine.